# No Sound via HDMI on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, hdmi

yesterday I set up my PC with Kubuntu 16.04 and all went fine except that there is no sound via HDMI.
So I asked Google what to do, but I didn't find a solution for the problem.

That's the current state:

The output of aplay -l is

```
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sub-Geräte: 0/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], Gerät 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], Gerät 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
```

speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3 shows:

```
Wiedergabe-Gerät ist hw:0,3                                                   
Stream-Parameter sind 48000 Hz, S16_LE, 2 Kanäle                
Verwende 16 Oktaven rosa Rauschen                                     
Fehler beim Öffnen des Gerätes: -16, Das Gerät oder die Ressource ist belegt
```

For non-german users: This means, that I can't use card 0, device 3 because it's busy.

When I run speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,7 I can hear the pink noise.

So I assume that there are some settings which have to be switched. But I don't know what and how. 
Can anybody help me? I'm grateful for any kind of hint!

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: well if the device is busy kill it, ps aux | grep alsa and retry speaker-test -c 2 -r 48000 -D hw:0,3 you're wanting the card and the device also check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

After updating to 16.04 I also had problems playing sound over HDMI. Up to now I had always been able to change the output with PulseAudio. Under 16.04 this option didn't appear anymore. After some clicking around I found a solution that makes this possible again. It's quite simple.

- Click on the loudspeaker symbol in the lower right corner of the control bar.
- Click on the settings icon in the upper right corner.
- Click on Volume on the left.
- Select the *Advanced* tab.
- Here should be a built-in sound device out and a built-in sound device Analog Stereo Duplex.
- Click on the button where it says *Off*.
- Select an HDMI output.
- Save.
- Now the HDMI output appears at the Devices and there is once again in PulseAudio the button where you can adjust the output device.